# Access BOTHRESH value of IBM MQ using JMS API

Tags: java, spring-boot, websphere, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I'm using spring boot with `mq-jms-spring-boot-starter` to create a JMS Listener application which reads a message from a queue, process it and forward the message in to another queue.

In case of a poison message scenario, I'm trying to generate an alert. However, in order to not generate multiple alerts to the same message, I'm thinking of comparing the `JMSXDeliveryCount` with `BOTHRESH` value and generate the alert in the last redelivery before sending to the BOQ.

`BOTHRESH` and `BOQNAME` are configured for the source queue.

```java
    @JmsListener(destination = "${sourceQueue}")
    public void processMessages(Message message) {
        TextMessage msg = (TextMessage) message;
        int boThresh;
        int redeliveryCount;
        try {
            boThresh = message.getIntProperty("<WHAT COMES HERE>");
            redeliveryCount = message.getIntProperty("JMSXDeliveryCount");
            String processedMessage = this.processMessage(message);
            this.forwardMessage("destinationQueue", processedMessage);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (redeliveryCount >= boThresh) {
               //generate alert here
            }
        }
    }
```

How should I get the value of `BOTHRESH` here? Is it possible at all? I tried to get all the available properties using `getPropertyNames()` method and following are all the properties I see.

- `JMS_IBM_Format`
- `JMS_IBM_PutDate`
- `JMS_IBM_Character_Set`
- `JMSXDeliveryCount`
- `JMS_IBM_MsgType`
- `JMSXUserID`
- `JMS_IBM_Encoding`
- `JMS_IBM_PutTime`
- `JMSXAppID`
- `JMS_IBM_PutApplType`

Comment: If you have define BOTHRESH and BOQNAME attributes for your queue, MQ JMS will automatically move poison messages (basically when delivery count exceeds BOTHRESH) to BOQNAME.

Comment: @Shashi, yes that's correct. But I need to generate an alert from the Java Application before poison message is moved to the BOQNAME. And I only want to generate this alert once for a message.

Comment: BOTHRESH and BOQNAME or IBM MQ Specific Queue attributes and they are not part JMS specification. So you can't use JMS APIs get those details. You will need to IBM MQ provided PCF classes for that purpose. Why not generate an alert once message arrives in BOQ?

Comment: @Shashi I see. I will have to think of an alternative approach then. BOQ may contain other messages that are not relevant so might not be possible. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it, but the code does need admin access to an admin channel, which may not be optimal for a client application.

The Configuration

```java
import com.ibm.mq.*;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import com.ibm.mq.constants.CMQC;

import java.util.Hashtable;

@Configuration
public class MQConfiguration {
    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    @Value("${ibm.mq.queueManager:QM1}")
    public String qMgrName;

    @Value("${app.mq.admin.channel:DEV.ADMIN.SVRCONN}")
    private String adminChannel;

    @Value("${app.mq.host:localhost}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${app.mq.host.port:1414}")
    private int port;

    @Value("${app.mq.adminuser:admin}")
    private String adminUser;

    @Value("${app.mq.adminpassword:passw0rd}")
    private String password;


    @Bean
    public MQQueueManager mqQueueManager() {
        try {
            Hashtable<String,Object> connectionProperties = new Hashtable<String,Object>();

            connectionProperties.put(CMQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, adminChannel);
            connectionProperties.put(CMQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, host);
            connectionProperties.put(CMQC.PORT_PROPERTY, port);
            connectionProperties.put(CMQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, adminUser);
            connectionProperties.put(CMQC.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, password);

            return new MQQueueManager(qMgrName, connectionProperties);

        } catch (MQException e) {
            logger.warn("MQException obtaining MQQueueManager");
            logger.warn(e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }
    
}
```

Obtain the Queue's backout threshold

```java
import com.ibm.mq.*;
import com.ibm.mq.constants.CMQC;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Runner {
    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    @Value("${app.mq.queue:DEV.QUEUE.1}")
    private String queueName = "";

    private final MQQueueManager mqQueueManager;

    Runner(MQQueueManager mqQueueManager) {
        this.mqQueueManager = mqQueueManager;
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner init() {
        return (args) -> {
            logger.info("Determining Backout threshold");
            try {
                int[] selectors = {
                        CMQC.MQIA_BACKOUT_THRESHOLD,
                        CMQC.MQCA_BACKOUT_REQ_Q_NAME };
                int[] intAttrs = new int[1];
                byte[] charAttrs = new byte[MQC.MQ_Q_NAME_LENGTH];

                int openOptions = MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF | MQC.MQOO_INQUIRE | MQC.MQOO_SAVE_ALL_CONTEXT;
                MQQueue myQueue = mqQueueManager.accessQueue(queueName, openOptions, null, null, null);
                logger.info("Queue Obtained");

                MQManagedObject moMyQueue = (MQManagedObject) myQueue;
                moMyQueue.inquire(selectors, intAttrs, charAttrs);

                int boThresh = intAttrs[0];
                String backoutQname = new String(charAttrs);

                logger.info("Backout Threshold: " + boThresh);
                logger.info("Backout Queue: " + backoutQname);

            } catch (MQException e) {
                logger.warn("MQException Error obtaining threshold");
                logger.warn(e.getMessage());
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you are mixing retriable and non-retriable error handling.
If you are tracking redelivers and need to send an alert, then you probably do not want to set a BOTHRESH value, and instead manage it all in your client-side code.

Recommended consumer error handling pattern:

1. If the message is invalid (ie.. bad JSON or XML) move to DLQ immediately. The message will never improve in quality and there is no reason to do repeated retries.
2. If the 'next step' in processing is down (ie. the database) reject delivery and allow redelivery delays and backout retries to kick in. This also has the benefit of allowing other consumers on the queue to attempt processing the message and eliminates the problem where one consumer has a dead path from holding up a messages.

Also, consider that using client-side consumer code to do monitoring and alerting can be problematic, since it combines different functions. If your goal is to track invalid messages, monitoring the DLQ is generally a better design pattern and it removes 'monitoring' code from your consumer code.

Comment: Hi Matt.   The BOQNAME/BOTHRESH are parameters on the QLOCAL AND back out count is a field in the MQMD of the message, but the actual back out logic is part of the IBM MQ classes for JMS.  See the IBM MQ Knowledge Center page [Handling poison messages in IBM WebSphere MQ classes for JMS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q032280_.htm) for more details.

Comment: The backout logic is QMgr-side (aka server-side). Its the same MQI or JMS. If the client calls rollback or rejects the messages, the QMgr handles the redelivery and eventual move the the BOQNAME (and adding of the DLH header). The MQMD.backoutCount is mapped to JMSXDeliveryCount header for JMS.

Comment: Please review the IBM MQ Knowledge Center page [DEFINE queues](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q085690_.htm), both attributes state "Apart from allowing its value to be queried, the queue manager does nothing based on the value of this attribute."

Comment: In the KC page above BOQUEUE goes on to say "IBM MQ classes for JMS transfers a message that is backed out the maximum number of times to this queue."  BOQNAME goes on to say "IBM MQ classes for JMS use the attribute to determine how many times back a message out."  KC page [Poison messages in XMS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/xms_cpoison_messages.htm) shows this is also true of XMS.

Comment: JoshMc-- thank you for pointing that out. That is an oversight on my part. I'll edit my response to clarify.